# How to retrieve the last data from non adjacent Excel columns and display it in a cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

[Spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/509kG.jpg)

Dear gurus,

I'm trying to create a mortgage simulator with Excel. As part of the spreadsheet, I decided to have a small section showing the current mortgage situation based on the monthly payment installments. One cell is meant to display the mortgage remaining to be paid. This cell must reflect the latest value calculated in other columns.
The columns where the monthly calculated remaining mortgage to be paid are not adjacent to one another, nor are they displayed in one continuous column. I have designed it this way to reduce paper waste when printing.. 2 years can be displayed side by side rather than underneath each other. Thus the range of cells where the data must be obtained is in multiple sections in the same spreadsheet. Please refer to my image for clarification.
As you can see, Year 1 has the range F18:F27. Moving on to Year 2 we get a new range to include in the function of L16:L27. Year 3 will have a new range F32:F43... and so on. 
While trying to enter the formula with the different ranges as follows: =INDEX((F18:F27&L16:L27),MATCH(9.99999999999999E+307,(F18:F27&L16:L27))) - in this case only using 2 ranges for now - I get a #VALUE error. Using one range (F18:F27) works. As soon as I add another range, the formula does not work. I tried to use the concatenator & instead of the , but it still didn't work.

Any ideas how to solve this?
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use LOOKUP+COUNT function

```
=LOOKUP(9.99E+307,IF(COUNT(L16:L27)>0,L16:L27,F18:F27))
```

Comment: This doesn't work unfortunately. Once I try to add further ranges - for example =LOOKUP(9.99E+307,IF(COUNT(L16:L27)>0,L16:L27,F18:F27,F32:F43)) - Excel gives me the error "You've entered too many arguments for this function"